# Is it possible to get consumed and remained gas from within a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, gas, gas-limit

How can I get consumed gas as well as remained gas (which is sent with tx by the caller) from within a smart contract in solidity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the gas that a transaction spends by subtracting `gasleft()` at the end of the transaction from `gasleft()` at the start.

```
function myFunction() returns (uint256)
{
    uint256 startGas = gasleft();

    // Your function 

    return (startGas - gasleft());
}
```

Comment: And just for the ease of possible future readers: it is GAS opcode (0x5a) which uses 2 gas itself. According to EVM docs: 'Get the amount of available gas, including the corresponding reduction for the cost of this instruction'

Answer (score 1):

You can check this previous post to get an idea about how to procced:
[Is gasleft() the best way to manage big loops in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/127382/is-gasleft-the-best-way-to-manage-big-loops-in-solidity)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code after these two lines

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

//add safeMath library
library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
        uint256 c = a - b;
        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, "SafeMath: division by zero");
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }
}

contract {
    using SafeMath for uint256; // Import SafeMath library
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    function deposit() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Amount must be greater than zero");
    
        // Deduct gas fees from the deposited amount
        uint256 gasCost = gasleft() * tx.gasprice;
        uint256 depositedAmount = msg.value.sub(gasCost);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(depositedAmount);
    }
}
```