# Is gasleft() the best way to manage big loops in solidity?

Tags: solidity, arrays, gas-limit, gas-estimate, out-of-gas

I'm developing an Smart Contract that has to iterate through an undetermined size list of ERC20 tokens, and make a swap for each token. I'm aware that you cannot loop an undetermined size list, because it could lead to get out of gas issues.

I recently discovered gasleft() helper, and I cannot imagine any other efficient way to achieve the process described above.

```
address[] private tokenList;
mapping(address => uint256) private tokenAmount;
mapping(address => uint256) private lastPosition; //Save last iteration 

function withdraw() public {
    uint256 startGas = gasleft();
    uint256 gasUsed;
    //Get how much gas consume each operation
    address token = tokenList[lastPosition[msg.sender]];
    swapTokensForEth(token, tokenAmount[token]);    
    uint256 gasIteration = startGas - gasleft(); //Gas consumption on first iteration

    while (lastPosition[msg.sender] < tokenList.length && gasleft() > gasIteration ){
        token = tokenList[i];
        swapTokensForEth(token, tokenAmount[token]);    
        lastPosition[msg.sender]++;
        gasUsed = startGas - gasleft();
    }
}
```

Note: swapTokensForEth is my function connected to Uniswap/Pancakeswap to make the swap and sell the token for ETH.

Is this a correct approach, or I'm missing something?

**UPDATE:**

The other approach is to estimate gas consumption from web3 and use the result as gasIteration value.

```
const txbase = {
    from: signer.address,
    nonce,
    to: process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    data
  };
  const gasLimit = await web3.eth.estimateGas(txbase);
```

Comment: Since `gasleft` itself uses gas as well, maybe it's better to use it once for an initial loop call and then use that result (plus an e.g. 10% buffer to compensate for unpredictable irregularities) for an estimate to countdown with a regulat `uint` or simlar. But it's just an untested idea, maybe you've found a better solution meanwhile?